# 1 on 1 Random Matchmaking

Tags: php, mysql, random, webrtc, p2p

I am developing a random chat application that matches a client with another "random" client. Pseudo-Random because the client would query a list of "open" clients and pick from the top of the list.

I have searched for an answer but seemingly no resources exist for a matchmaking solution based off of a relational database in mySQL. The problem I ran into is that if all clients were set to "search", then each(user) would try to connect to one(a) while the one(a) would be trying to connect to another(b). {*user is chasing a while a is chasing b simultaneously.}

What would be the simplest structure and process to connect two random clients to exchange information when both are in a pool of unmatched-clients?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps instead of having each client actively look for another one to connect to in the database, you could have all clients just enter themselves into the matchmaking pool. Then a separate process running on the server would check the database and match people according to whatever criteria you wish, and remove them from the 'searching' table. This would ensure people can't be matched simultaneously with more than one person.

I hope that helps somewhat conceptually.

Comment: Yes this is definitely a conundrum, how would you set up a php script to constantly check the pool from the database and act as a moderator to assign each user? That is the part I cannot get my head around.

Comment: I have recently made something similar. You can have a script with an unending while loop, that polls the database for searching users and when it finds two, it removes those entries from the searching table and sends connection information to each client. If the script finds nothing in the searching table, it will `sleep(1)` and then repeat. PHP isn't the best language to make long-running processes with of course, but if you use a process manager like Supervisord to make sure the script stays running in case it crashes, this is a decent solution.